# I type a word "divorce" message in computer without any intention

Tags: nikah

If I type a word "divorce" message in computer without any intention at the beginning but the intention about divorce comes up in the final alphabet and press Enter that word to Google, will it effected to my marriage?

Example: I typed "Divor..” and I just had the intention of divorce when I typed "..ce".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divorce means separating from something, as long as you didn't specify what, it is still vague and do not effect your marriage. If it can effect your marriage, if you have more than one wife, all your wives would get divorced.

Second thing you should address it to your wife itself, not to your browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer that was helpful to me.
I would like to know more.
In the case of any utterance that may be a kinayah and the wife is not mentioned in that utterance. It does not affect the marriage even if there is an intention for the wife.
Did I understand correctly?